# Python - Automatically detecting headers in excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm attempting to write a generic program that can detect and ignore headers. I have one dataset with a two-row header followed by the data values, and another with a single row header. How can I dynamically determine the total number of headers in each file and skip those? I can't use Sniffer because it is not a CSV file.

```
df = pandas.read_excel('ExcelFile.xlsx', header=[0, 1])
```

This considers both 0th and 1st row as header, where as my requirement is to automatically the program has to detect total number of headers present. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I don't think there is something already implemented because it depends on your data in the Excel.